# I want to use Kubernetes for sorting purpose for different fields like name and age etc

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying use my kubernetes for sorting purpose. Do we have any command line tools to achive the goal. Can someone help me to get this done. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very confusing and lacks anything valuable to help. Add more info in your question, like examples and desired output. What fields whose age?

Comment: @ovflak Please elaborate more. Your use case is not fully defined.

Comment: @Ovflak, It would be more meaningful to share the code and specify the language &   framework that you have worked on so far & what challenge are you facing.

Kubernetes is container orchestration platforms, and will not be able to do field sorting out of the box, without a containerized application deployed as Pod in Kubernetes Pod. I suggest you read up about Containerization tools like docker, before even starting on Kubernetes.